# How to print stars in range with number at the end?

Tags: python

I am trying to print a function like this:

```
***1
**22
*333
4444
```

the function could be like `star(n)` where n is 4. Can you help me please?

Comment: What have you tried and where did you stuck?

Comment: Hint: `print("*"*3)` will print 3 stars. And `print("1"*1)` will print 1 `1`.

Comment: And if you notice, `3 + 1 == 4`

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: i have tried 

for i in reversed(range(0,n+1)):
            line = (star * (i-1))

but i cannot seem  to print the numbers at the end ( i cannot concatenate the numbers after the stars)

Answer (score 0):

This will give the above output.

```
def star(n): 
    myList = [] 
    for i in range(1,n+1): 
        myList.append("*"*(n-i)+str(i)*i) 
    print("\n".join(myList)) 

star(4)
```

Output

```
***1
**22
*333
4444
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```py
def printStar(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        stars = '*'*(n-i)
        nums = str(i)*i
        print(f"{stars}{nums}")
```

Output:

```
***1
**22
*333
4444
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit faster goes this!

```py
def star(n):
    for i in range(n):
        a = ('*' if (n-j-1 > i) else i+1 for j in range(n))
        print(*a, sep='')
```